# Multipart POST using perl not fetching desired results

Tags: perl, post, multipart

I am trying to use an API using multipart entity. I guess there is something i am missing.

My current code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 #$request = $ua->request($request);
#my $results=$ua->request($request);
$content = $request->content; 

#print "Content-type: application/xml\n\n"; 

print $content; 
exit;
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?  What do you expect the above piece of code to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the content type you want to create to the arguments of POST and supply the file name as an array reference. This should work:

```
my $request=(POST 'http://servername/test.jsp', 
    Content_Type => 'form-data',
    Content      => [
        appGUID         => "Test",
        userId          => "User",
        password        => "<Password>",
        bugId           => "12345678",
        fileDescription => "trying to attach a file",
        external        => "false",
        Filedata        => [ "Path" ],
    ],
);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Stil also i am not getting the file attached but i am getting some XML response.

Comment: If the file is not being attached, you may want to check if your program can find the file with the `-f` operator.

Comment: @tauli Seriosuly, this might be the only full code example of how to use this properly on the internet.....